# Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0' inside docker container

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, cuda, gpu

I have created a docker image with the following Dockerfile

```
FROM python:latest
WORKDIR /root/my_dir
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN apt-get update &&\
        apt-get upgrade -y &&\
        apt-get install -y curl &&\
        apt-get install nano &&\
        pip3 install -r requirements.txt &&\
```

and then I use it as service describing it in the docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '2.2'

services:
  my_service:
    image: my_image
    volumes:
      - /root/my_dir:/root/my_dir
      - /usr/local/cuda-11.0:/usr/local/cuda-11.0
    environment:
      - LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib
    command: ["python3"]
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
  
  cuda:
    image: nvidia/cuda:11.0.3-devel-ubuntu16.04
    runtime: nvidia
    environment:
      - NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=all
    command: nvidia-smi
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
            - driver: nvidia
              count: 0
              capabilities: [gpu]
              driver: nvidia
```

Versions:

```
Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350
docker-compose version 1.29.0, build 07737305
docker-ce 5:20.10.7~3-0~ubuntu-xenial                  
docker-ce-cli 5:20.10.7~3-0~ubuntu-xenial
docker-ce-rootless-extras 5:20.10.7~3-0~ubuntu-xenial
docker-scan-plugin 0.8.0~ubuntu-xenial
nvidia-docker2 2.11.0-1
```

On my machine, I have installed cuda 11.0, and I use python 3.8 and tensorflow 2.4.0 as stated here

```
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu
```

I run the container with:
`docker-compose up`
all seems go well, but then when I attach to the container, I try to import tensorflow with python, but it gives me
`Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory;`

I also tried to set the same env variables as outside the container

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.0/lib64
CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda-11.0
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda-11.0/bin
```

but it has any effect.

I also tried several cuda docker images, nothing to do.

Comment: Did you test the docker image on another machine? to see if the problem remains

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you created in the docker composed two different services that cannot communicate with each other.
The best thing to do is to create an image with CUDA in which you install python and the requirememnts.txt.\

This is a sample of docker file:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.2.0-cudnn8-runtime-ubuntu20.04
WORKDIR /root/my_dir
COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y &&\
    apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip nano

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip && pip3 install -r requirements.txt

ENV NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES all
ENV NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES compute,utility
```

And this is the docker compose:

```
version: '2.2'

services:
  my_service:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - /root/my_dir:/root/my_dir
    command: ["bash"]
    stdin_open: true
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
            - driver: nvidia
              count: 1
              capabilities: [gpu]
```

Comment: @AndrewR. I get `manifest for nvidia/cuda:11.2.0-cudnn8-runtime-ubuntu20.04 not found`